# Trace formula on finite-dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a finite-dimensional complex Hilbert space and let $A$ be a linear operator on $\mathscr{H}$. Suppose I want to evaluate $\operatorname{Tr}e^{-tA}$, where $t$ is a nonnegative real parameter. The book I was reading states that, because $\mathscr{H}$ is finite-dimensional, $e^{-tA}$ is an entire function of $t$ so the following equation must hold:
$$\operatorname{Tr}e^{-tA} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\operatorname{Tr}\bigg{(}1-\frac{t A}{n}\bigg{)}^{n}$$
At first, I thought this formula was a consequence of Trotter's formula, but it seem it is not. Could someone help me understand why does it hold? I believe this is probably quite simple, but I could not deduce it by myself.

Comment: $e^{-tA}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{tA}n)^n$ holds by the same proof as for complex numbers, and then you can exchange the limit and the trace because everything is nicely continuous in finite dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is $m\times m$ and write $A=VTV^*$ the [Schur-Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) (the Jordan Form also works here, the point is that you get a triangular matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ in the diagonal), with $T$ triangular. Then
$$
e^{-tA}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^kA^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^kVT^kV^*}{k!}=V\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^kT^k}{k!}\,V^*.
$$
As $T$ is triangular, the diagonal entries of $T^k$ are $T_{11}^k,\ldots,T_{mm}^k$. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-tA})=\operatorname{Tr}\Big(V\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^kT^k}{k!}\,V^*\Big)
=\operatorname{Tr}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^kT^k}{k!}\Big)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^k\operatorname{Tr}(T^k)}{k!},
$$
where the exchange between the trace and the series is due to the trace being continuous. Now,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-tA})&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^k\sum_{j=1}^mT_{jj}^k}{k!}=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^kT_{jj}^k}{k!}=\sum_{j=1}^me^{-t\,T_{jj}}
=\sum_{j=1}^m\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1-\frac{t\,T_{jj}}n\Big)^n\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\Big(1-\frac{t\,T_{jj}}n\Big)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Tr}\Big(1-\frac{t\,T}n\Big)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Tr}V\Big(1-\frac{t\,T}n\Big)^nV^*\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Tr}\Big(1-\frac{t\,A}n\Big)^n
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, with multiplicities.

According to the spectral mapping theorem (with multiplicities), the eigenvalues of $e^{-tA}$ are exactly
$$e^{-t\lambda_1}, \ldots, e^{-t\lambda_n}$$
so since the trace is sum of eigenvalues we get
$$\operatorname{Tr} e^{-tA} = e^{-t\lambda_1}+ \cdots+ e^{-t\lambda_n}.$$

On the other hand, for each $k\in\Bbb{N}$, the eigenvalues of $I - \frac{tA}k$ are exactly
$$1 - \frac{t\lambda_1}k, \ldots, 1 - \frac{t\lambda_n}k$$
so we get
$$\operatorname{Tr} \left(I - \frac{tA}k\right) = \left(1 - \frac{t\lambda_1}k\right)+ \cdots + \left(1 - \frac{t\lambda_n}k\right).$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\operatorname{Tr} \left(I - \frac{tA}k\right) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1 - \frac{t\lambda_1}k\right)+ \cdots + \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1 - \frac{t\lambda_n}k\right) = e^{-t\lambda_1}+ \cdots+ e^{-t\lambda_n} = \operatorname{Tr} e^{-tA}$$
by the formula in $\Bbb{C}$.